# I can't find this IC marked 9A1Ky

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

What are the IC with the marking "9A1Ky" in the photo?

[image: 9A1Ky]

Comment: Please split this question into multiple questions, one per component as per our [identification guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710/51760).

Comment: if someone identifies the first IC correctly and someone else identifies the second IC correctly, then how will you determine which of the two answers is the correct answer?

Comment: Best guess on the SOT-23 marked 7002: 2N7002 transistor :-)

Comment: @winny thank you for your help but I want to know the IC marked 9A1Ky

Comment: @KareemElzeftawy Hence the smiley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [3PEAK TP181A1-CR](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2303010930_3PEAK-TP181A1-CR_C2902349.pdf) current-sensing amplifier.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Current-Sensing-Amplifiers_3PEAK-TP181A1-CR_C2902349.html))

Comment: Thank you very much @nanash1